# SQLAlchemy TypeError: ('Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row', 'HY000')

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I have a method that uses sqlalchemy

```
    def insert_amended_values(self, data):
        insert_stmt = """INSERT INTO amended (date, volume, price, updated)
        VALUES (%(date)s, %(volume)s, %(price)s, %(updated)s);"""
        crsr = self.connection.engine.raw_connection().cursor()
        crsr.executemany(insert_stmt, data)
```

Which takes is in data that is a list of dictionaries like

```
[
    {'date': '2020-06-27', 'volume': '30', 'price': 50, 'updated': '2020-10-21 17:17:50'},
    {'date': '2020-06-28', 'volume': '32', 'price': 48, 'updated': '2020-10-21 17:17:50'},
    {'date': '2020-06-29', 'volume': '26', 'price': 56, 'updated': '2020-10-21 17:17:50'}
]
```

but I get the error `TypeError: ('Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row', 'HY000')`

How can I convert the list of dictionaries to a list of lists or row while retaining the paramtized query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave your data in the `list` of `dict`, wrap your SQL statement in a SQLAlchemy `text` object and use the `:name` parameter style

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

# …

    def insert_amended_values(self, data):
        insert_stmt = sa.text("""INSERT INTO amended (date, volume, price, updated)
        VALUES (:date, :volume, :price, :updated);""")
        with self.connection.engine.begin() as conn:
            conn.execute(insert_stmt, data)
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me try that :)

Comment: Hi, is there anyway to do it using a cursor? Insert the list of dictionaries that is. 

Thanks